# Scaffold new tables and keep the existed ones?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework

I've scaffolded a few tables in a C# project. Now I need to scaffold a new table. I don't want to re-scaffold the existed ones because there were some changes.

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=...;Database=...;...;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer `
-OutputDir Models -Tables newTable
```

The command will get the following error.

> The following file(s) already exist in directory C:\Users....\Models: myContext.cs,newTable.cs. Use the Force flag to overwrite these files.

Using `-Force` will overwrite the existed code for the existed tables.

Comment: Just use [Entity Framework 6 Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.EntityFramework6PowerToolsCommunityEdition) or its EF-core version.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I wish there were a built-in way to add entities and update an existing context, but there doesn't seem to be.  I overcame this by using the `--context` option in the package manager console and just gave it a temporary name, e.g. `--context TempContext`.  This worked and generated the new table and the temp context.  Then I just copied the `public virtual DbSet<NewEntityType> NewEntityType { get; set; }` property and the `modelBuilder.Entity<NewEntityType>(entity =>` block from the `OnModelCreating` method in the temp context to my existing one.  After that, I deleted the temp context.  It's pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 6):

It will help you to change existing DbContext file.

If you have created a new table then New Class(entities) will create in your Models folder and if you drop existing tables then it will remove class(entities) in your Models folder.

**For Package Manager Console**

> BloggingContext is my own database context file, You have to change by
>   your name.

*Use commands in Package Manager Console*

`Scaffold-DbContext "Server=SERVER_NAME; Database=DATABASE_NAME; User Id=USER_ID; Password=PASWWORD;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -context "BloggingContext" -Force`

One dialog will open. Select appropriate option.

I choose "Yes to All"

and remove OnConfiguring() from BloggingContext.cs file.

Answer (score 0):

I normally keep a little text file to build up this command for scaffolding, adding every table to it.

Every time I execute it, all the models are overwritten.

If you have any logic in these models that you've written after scaffolding, on top of just the fields in the model, atm I recommend writing a wrapper class, one that extends from this model and has the additional methods implemented. This way your logic will not be overwritten and as long as the model name remains the same, the model wrapper will keep extending from it.

I'm only relatively new to scaffolding and am hoping there will be a better method in 2022!?

Answer (score 0):

It has been years, but up to today still, scaffolding does not support creating classes on new tables/views and updating dbcontext only. My workaround is to copy out the existing classes to another directory, then delete all the classes in the model directory, run the scaffolding with --no-build, and copy over copied classes, except dbcontext back into the model directory.

It is cumbersome, but at least did the job.

Maybe can put this feature on a wish list for the next EF version.